# How can I save data from httpclient at the data service and how can I loop trough my json object

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I have a json object generated trough

```
$json_str = file_get_contents('php://input'); echo json_encode($json_str);
```

which looks like:

```
0:[{"dok_1": "78",
"dok_45": "556",
"dok_e": "cde",
"dok_cd": "678",
"dok_bv": "5z",
"dok56": "rtz",
"dok_z6": "abc",
"dok_u8": "123"}]
```

And I am importing the data in my Angular App Http Service with

```
onGetData() {return this.httpCient.get('https://www.mywebpage.com/...');}

users;

onGet() {this.httpService.onGetData().subscribe(data => this.users = data);}
```

which works perfekt.

How can I store the above json object in my http Service or in a data Service?

Is there something like

```
addData(users: object) {
    this.users.push(data);
  }
```

to save data and

```
getData() {
    return this.users;
  }
```

to get data back? Or how can I save the json object at the http service or data service? Do I need an extra data service or is a http service good for saving this json object?

And how can I loop trough the json object?

Is there something like

```
<li *ngFor="let user of users">{{user}}</li>
```

? But how can I get access on of the keys to an key values to loop trough each line?

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Is it then a json string? How can I loop trough in Typescript?

Comment: It is either [JSON](http://json.org) or any of the supported types (string, number, array, object) after it has been parsed

Comment: So, there's no need to "save the object"; you're getting data, and you pass it to your view, where it's rendered. The [Angular Tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2) has demonstrations on how to get the data onto your page. If you have a specific question after having gone through the entire tutorial, please ask that question.